# reshape numpy array with a[:,None]

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following, what is `a[:,None]` means?

```
import numpy as np    
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[:,None]
```

Comment: It will add an extra dimension to the array, making it a 5x1 array.

Comment: `numpy.newaxis` is the same as `None` so everything in that duplicate is valid